# Dual Scale XY plot Example

Tags: androidplot

Am trying to zoom & scroll the DualScaleXYPlotExampleActivity.java provided by Android plot. So I added the necessary code for zoom & scroll to the same example code. But while trying to zoom, what I observed is only 1 graph is zooming, graph area is displaying 2 graphs, but single graph is zooming. Can anybody please help me with this issue, how can I zoom both the graphs.

Answer (score 0):

The dual scale example uses a bit of a hack to gain effect. I mean that with the utmost respect as it is a pretty clever hack.  Essentially a second plot is overlaid on top of the first.  The main thing to make sure of is that anything your zoom/scroll code does to plot1 is also done to plot2.  If after making sure that's the case you still have trouble, you'll need to update your question with the code for your zoom/scroll routines.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thanks Nick, am able to zoom the Dual Scale example code, actually I foundout the problem i.e.

@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
         switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // Start gesture
                firstFinger = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());
       --------------------
       --------------------
Whenever "onTouch" is getting called, View-ID was not correct check below

com.example.plotexample.DualXYPlot{43b52138 V.ED.... ........ 0,0-1080,1701 #7f080002 app:id/myXYPlot_R}

Solution:-

Implementing the Touch Event Listener as shown below i.e.

dual_scale_xy_plot_example.xml:-

    <RelativeLayout 
               android:id="@+id/sectionGraph" 
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:layout_marginTop="0px"
               android:layout_marginBottom="0px"
               android:layout_marginLeft="0px"
               android:layout_marginRight="0px">

                    <com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
                        android:id="@+id/mySimpleXYPlot_L"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        androidPlot.title="A Simple XY Plot"
                        androidPlot.graphWidget.gridLinePaint.color="#000000"/>
                    <com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
                        android:id="@+id/mySimpleXYPlot_R"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        androidPlot.title="A Simple XY Plot"
                        androidPlot.graphWidget.gridLinePaint.color="#000000"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

DualScaleXYPlotExampleActivity.java:-

private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
--------------
--------------

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.dual_scale_xy_plot_example);

            mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.sectionGraph);

            mRelativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(
                    new RelativeLayout.OnTouchListener() {
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motion) {
                            System.out.println("Coming to onTouch");
                            myXYPlot_L.onTouch((View)myXYPlot_L,motion);
                            myXYPlot_R.onTouch((View)myXYPlot_R,motion);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
               );
}

-------------
-------------

This solution is working fine for me.........
```